# Converting many xmls into a multiline csv with python

Tags: python, xml, csv, amazon-s3, xml-parsing

I have about 30,000 xmls that I would like to convert into separate rows of a large csv. The issue is that the xmls all contain differing numbers of tag names and differing subtrees. Here are three examples, (it seems easier to give links rather than reproduce long xml code):

https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201500509349300700_public.xml

https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201503169349202170_public.xml

https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201532889349300828_public.xml

Here is what I have so far for code:

```
import os
import json
import requests
import xmltodict
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import collections
import csv


files = list(os.listdir())
for f in files:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        root = tree.getroot()
        loopdict = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Then at this point, the best I can come up with is to create a separate list for each tag and use root.iter() to go through until it finds it and append its value to the list. Like so:

```
for x in root.iter(tag='{http://www.irs.gov/efile}EIN'):
        if len(x.text) <1:
            EIN.append('NA')
            break
        else:
            EIN.append(x.text.replace("{http://www.irs.gov/efile}",""))
            break
```

However, this won't account for some xmls which have more occurrences of a field than others or some which have fields that aren't present in others. Ideally, I would like to just flatten each xml and turn each field into a separate column, with NAs in place for rows which don't have a value for that column. Then, I would just append this row to a dataframe that would eventually contain data for all the 30k xml files I have saved.

I've been stuck trying various solutions for the last few days and am coming up short. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: "The issue is that the xmls all contain differing numbers of tag names and differing subtrees." - that sounds as if the data is totally unsuited to CSV representation.

Comment: But there are enough common categories to make a csv representation feasible.